# Python: I need to extract certain values from a data frame and create a new dataframe

Tags: python, filter, row

Sorry for the ask but I'm a python-noob and I need a help.

So, I have this csv (https://www.kaggle.com/jtrofe/beer-recipes) and I need to extract certain values.

I want to create a new data frame with same columns and values, but I want to extract from the columns "Style" only the "American IPA, American Pale Ale, Saison, American Light Lager e American Amber Ale". And create a data frame with this.

Someone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! In order to be more helpful, it would be good to see the code for what you've tried so far, based on the [pandas indexing and selection docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) and what went wrong with your attempts. See this link on creating a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html?highlight=iloc#pandas.DataFrame.iloc) indexing and the boolean series generator [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html?highlight=isin#pandas.Series.isin):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Read in the full data set, check its size
original_df = pd.read_csv('recipeData.csv', encoding='latin-1')
print(original_df.size)  # 1698803

# Store your desired styles for filtering in a python list
styles_list = "American IPA, American Pale Ale, Saison, American Light Lager, American Amber Ale".split(', ')

# Filter using .loc and a boolean mask (checking if each 'Style' value is in your list)
new_df = original_df.loc[original_df['Style'].isin(styles_list)]
print(new_df.size)  # 608419
```